# How to write to SQLite3 from multiple thread through ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord, sqlite

I want to write from multiple threads to the same SQLite3 table, which raises an exception that says:

```
A, ActiveRecord:     (0.2ms)     begin transaction
B, ActiveRecord:     (0.1ms)     begin transaction
A, ActiveRecord: SQL (0.6ms)     INSERT INTO "actions" ..
A, ActiveRecord:     (46.6ms)    commit transaction
B, ActiveRecord: SQL (5090.3ms)  INSERT INTO "actions" ..
B, ActiveRecord: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "actions" ...
```

Well I believe to understand what is happening. The database can't leave it's looked state anymore because there is still one transaction open.

How can I make sure, that only one transaction will be opened at a time? Maybe there is a solution, which I don't have to check this everytime I begin a new transaction.

Should I design that differently? Is there a easy solution to queue the transaction within a separated thread? What would you suggest?

Comment: Interesting question it would be good if somebody will ask.

Comment: Don't use SQLite for anything serious and/or in production. It's a pain in the ass.

Comment: Tell me about the other pitfalls, please!

Answer (score 0):

sqlite does not support concurrency, you should use either locking or try with a timeout on your connection specification

```
dev_sqlite:
  adapter: sqlite3
  dbfile: db/dev.db
  timeout: 15000
```

Then you'll only get a BusyException if it takes more than 15 minutes to get the db connection.

Comment: 15000 ms are 15 seconds. I've already set a timeout of 5 seconds, which is more than enough, because it one single records at the moment. I know that SQLite does not support concurrency, but this should not happen, what happens, right?